# ViewGroup Subclass for onInterceptTouchEvent

Tags: android, subclass, touch-event, viewgroup

My layout looks likes this:

[image]

I use a `RelativeLayout` which contains `llMain` and `scroll`. In `llMain`, I have two other `LinearLayouts`: `ll1` and `ll2`. And each of those `LinearLayouts` contains two `Buttons`.

I want to be able to swipe anywhere on `llMain` to call a certain function. But I also want to be able to click on the `Buttons` which are also in `llmain`.

So I tried implementing `onInterceptTouchEvent`. If I swipe on a `Button` I want `onInterceptTouchEvent` to intercept the call to the `Button's` `onTouchEvent` and perform a swipe action. And if I simply click on a `Button` I do not want the `onInterceptTouchEvent` to be called. Rather, I want the `Button's` `onTouchEvent` to be called and perform a `Button` click

I created a `Subclass ViewGroup` for `llmain` but I am having trouble implementing it correctly. It is not recognizing the swipe movements, only the click. Can someone please take a look and help:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.relativeLayout);

        swipeLinearLayout = new Container(this); //this is supposed to connect to llmain

    }

    private class Container extends LinearLayout {

    public Container(Context context) {
            super(context);
      }
      private float mLastX=0;
      private float mLastY=0;

      @Override
      public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                swipeLayout() //if event recognized as swipe, then swipe
                break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  float x = event.getX();
                  float y = event.getY();
                  float xDelta = Math.abs(x - mLastX);
                  float yDelta = Math.abs(y - mLastY);

                  if (yDelta > xDelta) {
                      return true;
                  }
                  break;
          }

          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          ButtonClick(); //if event is click, then perform button click
        return true;
      }
    }
}
```

My `swipeLinearLayout` does not connect properly to my `llmain`. Therefore it does not perform the swipe or click actions. How do I fix this?

Comment: use a GestureDetector for swipe gesture detecting,  it is much more easier

Comment: I used GestureDetector for swipe but the Touch event was consumed by the Child view which is the Button! That's why I decided to use onInterceptTouchEvent instead.

Comment: i didn't say you shouldn't use onInterceptTouchEvent, i said: use GestureDetector (together with onInterceptTouchEvent)

Comment: Oh interesting...would u be able to explain how to do that - sorry i'm just a bit new at android and handling touch events. But that seems like a good idea'

Answer (score 3):

use this GestureDetector:

```
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFling " );
        return true;
    }
};
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, listener);
```

and call it like that in your custom ViewGroup (Container class):

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
   gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks! just a few questions: 1. Does the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener go inside onCreate?
2. Another problem I had was that my Container is not programmed correctly- it does not connect to my llMain. Do you know why or how to fix it?

Comment: i created it in onCreate but you should add it to your Container class,  ad 2) i don't know what you mean

Comment: regarding 2: this code in my onCreate does not work:  swipeLinearLayout = new Container(this)

Comment: Also, does the GestureDetector gestureDetector go in onCreate or Container? (Sorry for all the questions. and thanks for all your help)

Comment: add the GestureDetector as a field in Container class,  ad 2) call setContentView(yourView) in onCreate

Comment: Hopefully this will be the last question. I already have a setContentView in my onCreate. And it's for the entire Relative Layout. Inside my Relative Layout I have the Linear Layout with the Buttons (as shown in the diagram). So I did setContentView(R.id.relativeLayout). Do you get the problem?

Comment: so add lin layout to the rel layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66605/discussion-between-user2456977-and-pskink).